# After form submit get the id from databse of last record

Tags: php, mysql

I need help for my web service project where user create an order when submit the order form, Driver get notification with accept or reject the order and when he accept order details list display to him. these all process done with order form submission. my all coding working fine. I don't  understand where from get id of current order list. plz give solution. thx

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['order_form']))
{
mysql_connect('localhost','root',''); 
mysql_select_db('live_help');

$user = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['mobile'];
$password = $_POST['address'];
$password = $_POST['order_item'];
$password = $_POST['price'];

$sql= mysql_query("insert into `json_web`(user,mobile,address,order_item,price) values('$user','$mobile','$address','$order_item','$price')");
if($sql)
{
    echo 'Value Saved';
}
}
?>
<form name="order_form" action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="user">
<input type="text" name="mobile">
<input type="text" name="address">
<input type="text" name="order_item">
<input type="text" name="price">
<input type="submit" name="field1" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: clearly read this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `mysql_insert_id();` to grap the last insert id. Take a look for more information 
[mysql_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

> **Warning:**
>   mysql_* is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:

Comment: Please this is deprecated , Use PDO or mysqli

Comment: thx jogesh for solve my problem very easy , I am sick of this issue from two days

Comment: I want to vote and accept the answer but i dont have much reputation ok bye :)

Answer (score 0):

After your mysql_query(); you can do this:

```
$id = mysql_insert_id();
```

mysql_insert_id(); retrieves the ID of the last inserted element to the database.

Comment: Please don't use **mysql_** as it's **deprecated**. Please consider changing to **mysqli_** or **PDO**. `mysql_` will be removed in the next distribution of PHP and already throws deprecation notice errors. Also, there is no reason to have backticks on `\`json_web\`` as that table does not represent a reserved keyword, contain special characters, or have white space.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysqli_insert_id()` as from [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

`mysqli::$insert_id -- mysqli_insert_id` — ***Returns the auto generated id used in the last query***

Comment: I will use this function in other web service project. i bookmark this frd

Answer (score 0):

In order to use mysql_insert_id() you need to add another field into the database table so you can have distinct order id for each order.

Perhaps you already have it, if not, add it:

```
   ALTER TABLE `json_web` ADD order_id INT(10) NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT;
```

Then just select from database, use mysql_insert_id()

Cheers